# Is there any possibility to clear all fields at a time using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

My web page has many fields and I don't want to write clear script for each field.

Is any possibility there to clear all fields in current webpage using selenium webdriver?

Comment: refresh your webpage... :D

Comment: Vivek Singh thanks for immediate response

Answer (score 3):

If you want to clear all the text boxes, then you can create a list of fields. you can get all the text box within single class like below.

**Note** : In below code I assumed all of your fields contain within one class.

```
List<WebElement> List1 = driver.getElements(By.ClassName("ABC"));
for(i=0;i<List1.size();i++)
{
List1.get(i).clear
}
```

Another simple way is Refresh your web page

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the calling a small javascript, invoked using JavaScript Executor -

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var iCount=0; iCount < elements.length; iCount++) {
    if (elements[iCount].type == "text") {
       elements[iCount].value = "";
    }
 }
```

Or JQuery fans :)

```
$("input[type=text]").val('');
```

@Vivek Singh - I do not agree that refreshing a page may be a solution, consider any netbanking applications, where refresh is not allowed. The above JS approach is much robust.

Comment: what about input type-text being readonly? if it gets its value from some event firing attached to it? Though i totally agree with you on #netbanking aspect. I commented on a general perspective. :)

Comment: What you are referring to can be classified as "RESET" the fields. I am answering from the perspective of "clearing the fields", there's a small difference in "reset" and "clear". In case of reset it may have to fire an event and set it as per original value. 
Agreed in that case another solution might be required. Usually forms have a reset method attached, that can be invoked. But yes this might not work read-only type elements. Also if its a read-only you might not really be bothered to reset/clear it too. :)

Comment: Check this link for reset of an HTML form. http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml